# Amplify Auth and Android: how to get guest session token?

Tags: android, postman, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-sdk-android

I have an Android app using Amplify Auth. I am able to use guest access and
secret keys, but not the session token. [Postman](https://www.postman.com/)
requires a session token when using temporary credentials.

As per the [Amplify documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/access_credentials/q/platform/android),
I use this code to get the keys:

```java
Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession(
    result -> {
        Log.i(TAG, "inside getGuestCredentials()...result....." + result.toString());

        AWSCognitoAuthSession cognitoAuthSession = (AWSCognitoAuthSession) result;
        Log.i(TAG, "Is user signed in: " + cognitoAuthSession.isSignedIn());

        switch (cognitoAuthSession.getIdentityId().getType()) {
            case SUCCESS:
                Log.i(TAG, "Guest IdentityId: " + cognitoAuthSession.getIdentityId().getValue());
                Log.i(TAG, "Guest access key: " + cognitoAuthSession.getAWSCredentials().getValue().getAWSAccessKeyId());
                Log.i(TAG, "Guest secret key: " + cognitoAuthSession.getAWSCredentials().getValue().getAWSSecretKey());
                String sessionToken = ((AWSSessionCredentials) mobileClient.getCredentials()).getSessionToken();
                Log.i(TAG, "Guest sessionToken: " + sessionToken);
                break;
            case FAILURE:
                Log.i(TAG, "failure Guest IdentityId not present because: " + cognitoAuthSession.getIdentityId().getError().toString());
                break;
            default:
                Log.i(TAG, "default guest session: " + cognitoAuthSession.toString());
                break;
        }
    },
    error -> Log.i(TAG, error.toString())
);
```

I then use an instance of `AWSMobileClient` (which I get using the escape hatch)
to get a session token.

This worked for a while, but suddenly I started getting this 403 message:

> "Message": "User: arn:aws:sts::xxxxxx:assumed-role/amplify-xxxxxx-unauthRole/CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform: execute-api:Invoke on resource: arn:aws:execute-api:xxxxxyyyyyyzzzz"

How can I get the session token?

Comment: If someone came across this question as i did, then I will post the answer here for those people. `((AWSTemporaryCredentials) ((AWSTemporaryCredentials) ((AWSCognitoAuthSession) session).getAwsCredentialsResult().getValue())).getSessionToken()` . The session here is got from `RxAmplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession()`